# Disabling the tr in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Month</td>
     <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

All the td have got input tag in it and
Suppose for some value of td, I want to disable whole tr
Is there a way to do it ?

**I am currently using Knockout JS**

Comment: Hello. Your question, as it stands, is not very clear. Please update it to provide more context. (What have you tried so far? What do you want to disable? What is the expected result? What is the result you are seeing etc). Consider making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand the problem better. Cheers :)

Comment: This is not clear, what is the 'i' you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to hide a row `<tr>` based on the value of an external variable?

Comment: no , actualy all the <td> have the input tags , so for some condition of first <td> i want to disable all the <td> in the same row

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

```
$("tr:nth-child(value-of-i)")
```

to disable the tr corresponding to the value of whatever variable(value-of-i in the example) you want, provided there are at least as many tr as the value of your variable is.

Comment: will  this peace of code be written within the <tr> Tag

Comment: No, you have to write it in <script></script> tag, or have an external .js file, (you also need jQuery), and make a function with the value-of-i as a parameter, so when you call the function, like hideTr(5), it will hide the 5th tr in the table.

Comment: I was seeking for the class or something rather to do this ,like we have Disabled also but cant be operated on <tr> or <td>

Comment: You can manipulate the tr or td however you want using javascript/jQuery.
I think that reading this can help you a bit https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp